# AVL Tree Code - I don't understand

Tags: c++, tree

```
void insert( const Comparable & x, AvlNode * & t )
{
    if( t == NULL )
            t = new AvlNode( x, NULL, NULL );
    else if( x < t->element )
    {
            insert( x, t->left );
            if( height( t->left ) - height( t->right ) == 2 )
                    if( x < t->left->element )
                            rotateWithRightChild( t );
                    else
                            doubleWithLeftChild( t );
    }
    else if( t->element < x )
    {
            insert( x, t->right );
            if( height( t->right ) - height( t->left ) == 2 )
                    if( x < t->left->element )
                            rotateWithRightChild( t );
                    else
                            doubleWithLeftChild( t );
    }
    else
            ; // Duplicate; do nothing
    t->height = max( height( t->left ), height( t->right ) ) + 1;

}

int height( AvlNode *t ) const { return t == NULL ? -1 : t->height; }
```

How can they cal the height of tree ?

> ```
>        1
>      0
>   -1
> ```

height(-1) - height(null) = 1 ?? Not balance ?

Comment: What exactly is it that you don't understand? Do you have problems understanding C++ syntax or is it just about the algorithm involved?

Comment: i really don't understand the way it calculate height of the tree ? algorithm I mean.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not 100% clear what you're asking. The code

```
AvlNode * & t
```

declares t to be a reference to a non-const pointer. So, the function insert may change the pointer object of the caller. Since pointers may be null the code probably uses a *function* called `height` as a shortcut to handle the special case of null pointers:

```
inline int height(AvlNode * tree) {
    return tree ? tree->height : 0;
}
```

(just my guess of what height could look like)

*Added after you editited your question:*
It seems each node posesses a member called `height` which is kept in sync and reflects the maximum length of the path from the current node to a leaf. Since a null pointer doesn't point to a node, the subtree would be empty which explains the special case in height() that returns -1.

Comment: int height( AvlNode *t ) const
{
   return t == NULL ? -1 : t->height;
}
This is the height function, I'm totally don't understand XD XD . Can you explain the tree ahead, the height must be totaled, right ?
Thx for comment.